# Autoplay for slider

Tags: jquery

I have a slider, this works very well so far. but now I still need an autoplay and have not got a clue how to implement this. somebody has an idea?

```
var current = 1;
var wDoc = $(document).width();
var box = $(".bg-box");
var boxLength = box.length + 2;
var clipUl = $('.clip ul');
var speedAnimation = 1000;
function slideBox(to) {
    if (to < 0) {
        clipUl.css('left', -((boxLength - 2) * wDoc));
        to = boxLength - 3;
    } else if (to > (boxLength - 1)) {
        clipUl.css('left', -(1 * wDoc));
        to = 2;
    }
    clipUl.stop().animate({
        left: -(to * wDoc)
    }, speedAnimation);
    current = to;
    currentNum = current;
    $('.pagging-box').removeClass('active');
    if (to > (boxLength - 2)) {
        currentNum = 1;
    }
    if (to == 0) {
        currentNum = boxLength - 2;
    }
    $('#pagg' + currentNum).addClass('active');

};
```

Comment: You want to slide every 5 seconds for example?

Comment: Try `setInterval(function(){ //code for next slide }, timeToWait)`. Define timeToWait = time in milliseconds as the display time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var startAutoPlay = function() {
    var time = 2000; // (2 seconds);
    current = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        slideBox(current);
        current += 1;
    }, time);
}

startAutoPlay();
```